# Javascript If else

Tags: javascript

So this is what it is asking: Define a function named calculateTaxRate that takes two arguments

salary (number from 1 to 74,900)
status (string that's either 'single' or 'joint')
If the status is anything other than 'single' or 'joint'

Return a string that says 'Better call an accountant'
If the salary is greater than 74,900
Return a string that says 'Better call an accountant'
Otherwise
Return the correct tax rate as a string using the table from http://www.efile.com/tax-service/tax-calculator/tax-brackets/

This is the function I created, But I am getting this in response:
calculateTaxRate
    ✓ returns a warning if the status is incorrect
    ✓ returns a warning if the amount is over 74,900
    1) returns the correct tax rate for a single filer
    2) returns the correct tax rate for a joint filer

I don't know how to return the correct tax rate for both single and joint filer? anybody have a solution?

```
function calculateTaxRate(salary,status) {
    if(status != 'single' || 'joint'){
        return "Better call an accountant"
    } else if(salary > 74900) {
        return "Better call an accountant" 
    } else if(salary < 74900 && 'single'){
        return "25%"
    } 
}
```

Comment: `status != 'single' || 'joint'` should be `status !== 'single' && status !== 'joint'`

Comment: `salary < 74900 && 'single'` is incorrect, but I have no idea what you're trying to write here, so I cannot offer a correction.

Comment: yeah thats the part I am trying to fix

Comment: not sure what would go there

Comment: Again, I have no idea what you're trying to write there, so I can't help.  Translate what you think it's doing into English, please.

Comment: } else if(status = 'single'){
        return '10%'
    } else if(status  = 'joint')
        return '10%'
}
var salary = 1 && 74900
var status = 'single' || 'joint'

Comment: haha sorry. So in the lesson it is asking for us to calculate the correct tax rate for if you are single or joint

Comment: Define a function named calculateTaxRate that takes two arguments

salary (number from 1 to 74,900)
status (string that's either 'single' or 'joint')
If the status is anything other than 'single' or 'joint'

Return a string that says 'Better call an accountant'
If the salary is greater than 74,900
Return a string that says 'Better call an accountant'
Otherwise
Return the correct tax rate as a string using the table from http://www.efile.com/tax-service/tax-calculator/tax-brackets/

Comment: Austin, please translate the line I indicated into *what you think it is doing*, in English.  Restating the entire question isn't helpful.

Comment: thats the exact instructions. I got the first part correct with saying that you need to 'better call an accountant' but i cant get it to return the correct tax rate for single and joint

Comment: sorry Im having a hard time describing what is going on over text

Comment: The part Im not figuring out is the end where it is saying "otherwise return the correct tax rate as a string using the table from .."

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for your purpose, and you can borrow it's structure, but you'll need to figure out the code for every other use case in the rest of the table you provided.

```
function calculateTaxRate(salary, status) {
    if (status !== 'single' && status !== 'joint') {
        return "Better call an accountant";
    } else if (salary >= 74900){
        return "Better call an accountant";
    } else if (salary > 74900 && status === 'single') {
        return "25%";
    }
}
```

The reason your code was not passing is because you wrote `if(salary < 74900 && 'single')` where you should have wrote `if (salary > 74900 && status === 'single')`. You need to make sure the status is equal to 'single', and the salary is greater than 74900, not the salary being simultaneously greater than 74900 and also equal to 'single', which actually still isn't even valid JavaScript syntax.

I hope this helps your understanding, but you are on your own for the rest of your assignment.